# Does Unity's radian / degree setting depend on user settings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote the following code in Unity's C#.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called 
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
         var rotationValue = "57.2958";
         this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(float.Parse(rotationValue), float.Parse(rotationValue), float.Parse(rotationValue));
    }

    void Stop()
    {
    }
}
```

This code only rotated 57.2958 degrees in my environment, but in someone else's environment, it rotated at a tremendous rate.

I had already set the value in Degree, but it behaved as if I had multiplied that value by 57.2958.

Is there an internal mechanism outside of Unity's scripting that allows users to choose whether to use Degree or Radian?

Comment: Are you calling this code inside of an update loop?

Comment: Please, provide the full code scenario, "someone else's environment" it's very generic.

Comment: >Jake.
Yes, I am calling this in the update loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All unity rotation functions take in Degrees, but Mathf functions take in Radians. Your code doesn't seem to be legal C# code, are you sure that's the code you used? You need to add "f" after your numbers so they are floats, otherwise they are doubles. This is the  correct code:

```
this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(57.2958f, 57.2958f, 57.2958f);
```

Note that you do not need to write "this", most developers do not, so you can  write it like this:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(57.2958f, 57.2958f, 57.2958f);
```

The code should NOT be different on a different device. I strongly recommend you update your above code with an example that  both devices used, clearly showing the difference, and some values we can see.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm actually converting a string to a float using the float.Parse(). I have rewritten the original question. I'm sorry.

Comment: Just curious, what c# are you using? It should be var rotationValue = "57.2958"; right?